# Horizontal percentage stretching of children

Tags: c#, maui

What component in MAUI would I use to accomplish such a chart?

[image]

It should stretch to 100% width and the elements should have relative widths.
Is this possible with XAML only?

I thought about a grid with one row, but I can't iterate over the children.
Or a horizontal stackpanel, but it won't stretch.
Any idea?

Comment: What's the difficulty in using Grid?  That is what `*`, `2*` etc are for. If you mean the children are determined dynamically, then can't do in xaml; you'll have to create it in c#.

Comment: Yes, but that would need a fixed list of children. There is no ItemsSource property in a grid. Ok, maybe i'll use a grid and add the columns in code behind.

Comment: Right; no ItemsSource because there would be no way to tell grid the row/column/height/width values per child. That's why it can't be done with xaml only.